# Unique reference number based on date

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

I have a infopath form published on sharepoint site. There is a field with reference number that need to be filled automatically based on date.

For example:

today is `11.apr.2019` and reference number should be **0001** ( no matter how many forms are generated)
tomorrow `12.apr.2019` reference number should be **0002** for all forms created.

Is there any workaround on this?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by setting up a rule when the form first loads that checks the date and depending on how many days have passed since day 1, you can add that to the reference number. You will have to use concat and substring to get the value to look like "0001" instead of just "1".